# Integrate WSO2 API Manager with third party api gateway like kong

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I´m interested in using the store and the developer portal. In some cases I want to integrate third-party gateway like kong.

The documentation from WSO2 API Manager 2.x says:
 - Components usable separately: developer portal can be used to catalog
   APIs deployed in third-party gateways
   (https://wso2.com/api-management/features/)

Do you have more information about that feature and how to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

Technical this is feasible but requires some work. I've found that someone did it with Intel Expressway Service Gateway.

You would need to implement a custom handler in WSO2 and connect it with Kong. But as the features might differ, the UI may not perfectly fit.

Besides than offering extension points, WSO2 has no real interest in supporting this as the API Gateway is the core component and all of their business models are based on it.